# favicons on are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon

Favicons are broken on some sites.
Some sites show the icons swapped (for example, money.se using movies.se icon). On this meta (and few others sites) the icons aren't swapped :

Same hot network questions being seen on SO , and SO META respectively
[image: hot_network_questions_favicon_bug]

money.se

[image: money_se_favicon_bug]

reproduced on ie10 and chrome 47.0.2526.111 on W7 and firefox 38 on ubuntu 15.04

Edit : 
The site with wrong icons starts somewhere near ja.so, and they are using the next (alphabetically?) icon, writes.se (the last one) has no icon atm.

Edit2:
v=93b511aee284 headers :
Request

```
Host: cdn.sstatic.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332639/favicons-on-are-broken
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 02:41:01 GMT
If-None-Match: "aeb7f5ca30f8d11:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Response

```
Age: 1130
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 13:42:09 GMT
Etag: "aeb7f5ca30f8d11:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 62
X-Served-By: cache-gru7125-GRU
X-Timer: S1471441329.750093,VS0,VE0
```

Comment: I purged the CDN, so these should look OK now. Do they?

Comment: @Oded no, they still swapped

Comment: Strange. I've issued another purge. Can you do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) to fetch a fresh version and not a browser cached one?

Comment: @Oded hard-refresh, another machine, the bug persists. this is only affecting me?

Comment: Probably not, but difficult to know. Can you edit in the HTTP headers youget for this request? http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=93b511aee284

Comment: @Oded added the headers

Comment: @Oded just for reference, the favicons being used on meta is  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=1e9861561e7d while the one (bugged) being used on other sites is http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=1e9861561e7d

Comment: I've run the purge once more. Can you confirm the content length for  http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=1e9861561e7d ? Should be 64393.

Comment: @Oded yes, the length is 64393 and the favicons are correct c:

Comment: That suggests you are getting the correct file. Which is the same I am getting, so not sure why you are seeing a different result.

Comment: @Oded this is after your last purge, before the image was smaller. In fact it was missing the "L2P"

Comment: OK - good. So - fixed?

Comment: @Oded yes it's fixed

Comment: cross-site dupe at MSE: [“Hot Network Questions” website icons scrambled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283497/165773). @Oded is it [meta-tag:status-completed] too? Also comments over there refer similar issue reported at [stats meta](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/why-am-i-seeing-the-se-network-icons-exchanged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a static content deployment race where the CDN might end up caching the wrong (old) version of an image.

This is what you were seeing.

We are working on fixing our deployment process so this doesn't happen, but have not solved it yet.

Comment: `[status-mostly-kinda-completed]`

Comment: @CodyGray `[status-almost-fixed-but-don't-hold-your-breath]`

Comment: @CodyGray `[status-still-a-problem-two-years-later]`